# Will I get another's bounty if I answer my question?

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

The hypothesis:

1. I post a question.
2. Another users puts a bounty on my question.
3. I answer the question.
4. I accept my answer.

What happens to the bounty?

---

I keep reading [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) again and again, but I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bounty won't be awarded automatically when you accept an answer—you can't choose who gets the bounty, because you haven't started it. However, the person who started the bounty can award it to your answer, and then you'll get the reputation assigned to the bounty.

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't matter if I accept the answer or not, the person who put the bounty will decide where he can give it!

Comment: @gsamaras:  The other part to this is if at least two people upvote your answer afterwards, you would automatically qualify for half of the bounty should the person who started the bounty not award it to you.

Comment: @Makoto That would happen not only if the person didn't award the bounty to the OP, but if he didn't award the bounty at all.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again Gothdo, but I need guidance. You see I have asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964007/active-tasks-is-a-negative-number-spark-ui), where another guy and me answered. I am not sure which is the best answer, since there is some overlap (we hit a bug). I am afraid that accepting an answer will not allow the bounty giver to judge neutrally. Can I leave the question without an accepted answer, wait for him to give the bounty and then accept the answer? If you find it interesting, upvote for more to see, since there is more, as my update suggests

Comment: @gsamaras I think the fact that the question has a bounty shouldn't change which answer you accept. On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with waiting for the bounty to end before accepting an answer.

Comment: I see, so he *can* award the bounty, even if no answer is accepted at that time! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are eligible to receive the bounty because the bounty is not yours.  A key paragraph of the resource you linked:

> **If I offer a bounty on someone else's question, can I award the bounty to their answer?**
>
> Yes, a bounty can be awarded to any answer except one posted by the
>   person offering the bounty.
>
> This means that if you offer a bounty on someone else's question, and
>   the original poster of that question posts an answer, you can award
>   the bounty to their answer.

However, your self-accepting will not automatically qualify your answer for auto-awarding (emphasis mine)

> **If the bounty starter accepted** an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty (provided that the answer was posted during the bounty period).

It could however still get auto-awarded if it qualifies because it has a score of 2 or more.